# jquery dialog: close callback function called before close

Tags: jquery

Here I add option for dialog jquery UI

```
$("#dialog_renew").dialog("option", "buttons",
    [
        {
            text: "Close",
            close: function( event, ui ) {
                $('.dialog-renew-content pre').remove();
                console.log('closed');
            },
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

but when dialog popup opens, content is empty and log throws `closed` before I press close. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put close to wrong place

```
                                    $("#dialog_renew").dialog("option", "title", "Response");
                                    $("#dialog_renew").dialog("option", "close", function (event, ui) {
                                        $('.dialog-renew-content pre').remove();
                                        console.log('closed');
                                    });
                                    $("#dialog_renew").dialog("option", "buttons",
                                        [
                                            {
                                                text: "Close",
                                                click: function () {
                                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    );
```